# rails nested form confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views

I have this model :

```
class Employment < ActiveRecord::Base
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :month_lines
end
```

and there forms :

employment.new

```
= form_for @employment do |f|
      = f.fields_for :month_lines do |builder|
        = render "/month_lines/fields", :f => builder
```

month_lines/_fields

```
= f.number_field :days
```

I want to display month_line.year in the partial

How do I access the month_line object from in the _fields partial ?

Comment: Since your local :f is builder, then why doesn't `f.number_field :year` work in the _fields partial?

Comment: I need the display the value of year, not a field. Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very simple way but, for some weird reason, little known:

```
= f.object.year
```